# Returning bit for each Row in Sql which exist in Joined Table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to return an extra computed column as bit for each rowID that exist as foreign ke in Joined table.for example: `Select PId, PName from Part where PId in (Select distinct FkPid in joined Part`

Result should be like Pid| PName|Bit|

Thanks

Comment: What is the computation you're looking to do?

Comment: Just a check whether each record has any associations, if yes then return 1 or else 0 for each record.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Select PId, PName, CAST(CASE WHEN B.fkPid IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS BIT) ExistsOtherTable
from Part A
LEFT JOIN (Select distinct FkPid FROM [joined Part]) B
ON A.PId = B.fkPid
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply do a left join!!!!

```
Select PId, PName, cast (isnull(OtherTable.FkPid,0) as bit) as [Bit]  from Part left join 
OtherTable on Part.PId=OtherTable.FkPid
```